# Would this question be on-topic on this site?

Tags: discussion, suitable-question

We have this question on Super User: [Drupal image. Files storing to wrong place. Imagecache?](https://superuser.com/questions/168510/drupal-image-files-storing-to-wrong-place-imagecache)

It's off-topic for Super User, for sure. However, I'm not sure where to refer the user to. He is obviously in a webmaster position, but he is mostly asking about why something doesn't work correctly in drupal. I checked the FAQ, but I lack knowledge on the subject to judge if it's matching or not.

Is this question on-topic on this site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's on topic for this site. I don't think it's on topic for stackoverflow unless it is about programming.

Comment: Ok, question closed on Super User, and recommendation about this site written. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest sending him to Stack Overflow.  It could get answered here as well but Stack Overflow should definitely be able to answer it.